# leaflet mouse hover popup through array list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, leaflet

i want to display a popup on mouse hover,i want to show names on popup,which will  be select from the array list,i placed multiple markers on map at different latlon,now i want to display a popup(which contain name) for particular latlon,this is my code,where i want to show my district name on mouse hover,now i am getting the popup text on mouse hover but i don't know how can i call my array list in popupcontent,any one can suggest what i should do?

```
var planes = [
        ["Jodhpur",26.28, 73.02],
        ["Bikaner",28.0229,73.3119],
        ["Churu",28.3254,74.4057],
        ["Ganga Nagar",29.9038,73.8772],
        ["Hanumangarh",29.1547,74.4995],
        ["Jaisalmer", 26.9157,70.9083],
        ["Jalore",25.1257,72.1416],
        ["Jhunjhunu",28.1289,75.3995],
        ["Nagaur",27.1854,74.0300],
        ["Pali",25.7711, 73.3234],
        ["Sikar",27.6094,75.1399],
        ["Sirohi",24.7467,72.8043],
        ["Barmer",25.7532,71.4181],

        ];
        for (var i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
            marker = new L.marker([planes[i][1],planes[i][2]],{icon: myIcon}).addTo(map).bindPopup('<div id="chart" class="chart"></div>');
  marker.on('click', onMarkerClick, this);

  /*var currentMarker = planes[i][0];
    currentMarker.on('mouseover', currentMarker.openPopup.bind(currentMarker));
    */

  marker.on('mouseover', function(e) {
  //open popup;
  var popup = L.popup()
   .setLatLng(e.latlng) 
   .setContent('Popup')
   .openOn(map);
});


    }
```

Comment: `.setContent()` kind of tells you everyting

Comment: but i want to show my array list names like jodhpur,barmer etc.

Comment: Create a closure inside the loop, then you will be able to access the district names inside the `mouseover` callback `(function(index){... planes[index][0] ...})(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter your array to return the name based on lat and/or lng

```
 marker.on('mouseover', function(e) {
    var name = "";
    $.each(planes,function(i,v){
       if (v.indexOf(e.latlng[0]) > 0) {//test if the lat is in the array
          name = v[0];//get the name
       }
    })

    var popup = L.popup()
       .setLatLng(e.latlng) 
       .setContent('District: '+name)
       .openOn(map);
 })
```

Note: i am assuming e.latlng is a array of [lat,lng]

Comment: this is not work for me.i placed markers through index planes[i][1],planes[i][2],everything is working ,mouse hover on markers giving me the same popup text,but i want popup according to index.

Comment: what do you mean by not working, what exactly is not working?

Comment: at this index it return Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: i solved this error,your code is working,but still it is giving district on every hover not my arraylist names,previously i done this where i got popup by same name

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the marker1 name as per your marker name.

```
var marker1 = L.marker(23.0225, 72.5714).addTo(mymap)
    .bindPopup("Demo Content of Popup");

let isClicked = false

marker1.on({
    mouseover: function() {
        if(!isClicked) {
            this.openPopup()
        }
    },
    mouseout: function() { 
        if(!isClicked) {
            this.closePopup()
        }
    },
    click: function() {
        isClicked = true
        this.openPopup()
    }
})

mymap.on ({
    click: function() {
        isClicked = false
    },
    popupclose: function () {
        isClicked = false
    }
})
```